# What way I should stash user credentials?

Tags: java, desktop-application, credentials

I don't know if this is a valid question here but still. My desktop application has to store certain user details like `username`,`password` and other user credentials that together may make up a count of 10.

How do I store them ?

I need to store username and password so that there is automatic log in, when the application starts, just like *yahoo messenger* or *google talk*.

Comment: The user should authenticate against an authentication server (LDAP)? Using credentials like google mail?  or the credentials will be hardcoded in the application?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do, is uppon the entering of the credentials the first time, to create a text file on a file location like `c:\ApplicationData\MyApp\Cred` and encrypt the username and password in that file.

Now when the application starts, it should check if that file exists. If yes, it should decrypt it and provide the credentials to the authentication process. If the file does not exits, or it contains invalid data, it should prompt the user to enter the correct credentials.